# Java return a deleted file

Tags: java, playframework, java-io

I'm working on a Java Play endpoint that writes a CSV to a temp directory -> returns CSV -> and then deletes the CSV.

I do not want to rely on Play framework to delete the file, I also do not want to rely on an external process to watch the temporary directory.

What I want to do is have play return an unlinked file such that the garbage collector deletes the file after the file has been returned. But, being new to Java, I am not exactly sure how this is done. Any guidance the community may have around how to do this is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so, I think I figured it out. What I needed to do was open the file and create a link to it. Then I keep that link open and delete the file. I am still able to return the file because I have a reference to it in memory through the link that was created on reading / opening the file and *not* closing that fileReader. I then return the file. Once the program exits, the reference to the files location gets garbage collected and the file can is deleted from memory. Here's a sample class to demonstrate.

```
`
import java.io.*;

public class FileUtil {

public File generateFile() {
    File sampleFile = new File("./sampleFile.txt");
    try {
        FileOutputStream is = new FileOutputStream(sampleFile);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(is);
        Writer w = new BufferedWriter(osw);
        w.write("sample file text");
        w.write("testing new line");
        w.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Problem writing to the file sampleFile.txt");
    }

    String line = null;

    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(sampleFile);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        // do not close fileReader
        // leave it open so that we can delete the file and still return it
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file");
    }

    sampleFile.delete();

    return sampleFile.getAbsoluteFile();
}

public static void main(String[]args) {
    FileUtil myFile = new FileUtil();
    myFile.generateFile();
}
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector cannot delete a file, this is an operating system construct, well outside the scope of Garbage Collection.

What you can do though is create a temporary file:

```
File temp= File.createTempFile("myprefix-", ".suffix");
temp.deleteOnExit();
```

Which will be cleaned up by the JVM in due course.

Note: If security is a concern and you don't want files hanging around then this might be an issue.

I would also suggest that, if possible, you bypass the writing of the file and return the CSV `String` directly.  In your use case above, the temp file seems superfluous.

Comment: Temporary files are not removed by the VM. There is a `deleteOnExit` function on the `File` class, *but* you don't know *when* the VM exits and if it has the chance to delete those files, and how many it will have in the queue.

Comment: @M. le Rutte Good point, I've updated accordingly (I've also got some legacy code to analyse!).